# Lambdas in Exponential Distribution

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, distribution, exponential

In the following case I'm not exactly sure why the formula for y is: `y = lam * np.exp(-lam * x)`. Why is there a negative in front of the second lambda?

This is the total code.

```
lam = 0.5
x = np.arange(0, 15, 0.1)
y = lam * np.exp(-lam * x) # could also use stats.expon.pdf
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title('Exponential: $\lambda$ =%.2f' % lam)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Probability density')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The negative makes the exponential go to zero rather than to infinity as x goes to infinity.  The better question is why there's a lambda out front of the whole thing, and that's to scale the results to the total area is one, a requirement for all density functions.

Comment: Hey, could you possibly clarify how the lambda in in front of the whole thing scales the results? I'm still a bit confused as to how this works. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to integrate a function to get its area?  Integrate `exp(-lambda*x)` from zero to infinity.  You'll find the area is `1/lambda`.  To be a valid density function the area must be one, so you scale it by `lambda` -- `Integral[lambda*exp(-lambda*x)]` from zero to infinity will be 1 for any strictly positive finite value of `lambda`.  You can actually use this trick to convert pretty much any function `0 <= h(x) <= infinity` with finite area into a valid distribution by scaling it by the inverse of its area.

Answer (score 2):

Because that is the definition of an exponential distribution's PDF.  [Exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)